# Getting data from Rally getSettingsFields - checkboxfield

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox, rally

I recently posted about getting a combobox into the settings of a Rally app, now I'm trying to figure out how checkboxes work in settings.  I assumed they would work similarly [ish] but for some reason it's not [hence why i'm on this site again].

My checkbox field and getSettingsField function look like this right now:

```
getSettingsFields: function() {
    return [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
            defaultType: 'checkboxfield',
            items: [
                {
                    name: 'box1',
                    boxLabel: 'Box 1:',
                    inputValue: true,
                    value: true,
                    id: 'boxone'
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
}
```

At the top of my app I also have the following default settings set:

```
config: {
    defaultSettings: {
        box1: true
    }
},
```

I console.log()'d the setting for that checkbox inside the launch function and found that the setting starts at "true" but the checkbox is not originally checked.  When I check the box and save the settings, the setting stays at "true" and again unchecks when i go back to the settings tab.  This would all be okay, but when I save the settings with the box unchecked, the setting still stays as "true".

I tried changing the defaultSetting to false just for testing, but again I only got a "true" setting field for box1.  My logging line, `console.log('Setting: ' + this.getSettings());` is what is showing me the current value for each setting each time the app is loaded & each time the settings are changed.

The goal is to get the checkbox setting to read correctly [true / false or whatever syntax the settings come in] at the beginning of the app so a grid can be filtered later.  Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the settings tab is returning a string, so "true" is returned from the inputValue, not the boolean true value.  Also, the value setting is messing things up, so here's what I ended up using:

```
config: {
    defaultSettings: {
        boxes: "check"
    }
},
...
getSettingsFields: function() {
    return [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
            defaultType: 'checkboxfield',
            items: [
                {
                    name: 'boxes',
                    boxLabel: 'Box 1:',
                    inputValue: "one",
                    checked: this.getSettings().boxes.split(',').indexOf('one') > -1,
                    id: 'boxone'
                },
                {
                    name: 'boxes',
                    boxLabel: 'Box 2:',
                    inputValue: "two",
                    checked: this.getSettings().boxes.split(',').indexOf('two') > -1,
                    id: 'boxtwo'
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
}
```

I learned that the 'name' field is a generic field that should apply to all checkboxes that are related to each other in the settings panel.  The 'inputValue' field is the returned string to the settings field, and each returns to a string in `this.getSettings().boxes`.

I wanted to keep the boxes to remember if they were checked before, so that's where the line `checked: this.getSettings().boxes.split(',').indexOf('one') > -1` comes from.  If the string 'one' is in the settings, that means the index will be larger than one, so checked will be true and therefore the box will be checked next time someone opens the settings menu.